# Change my keyboard layout for my profile only

Tags: 14.04, bash, keyboard-layout, .profile

We are using ubuntu-server 14.04 ,  I want to change the keboard layout to querty only for my login , i want the other users remain having azerty ,  I know that I have to put a command line in some statup file , I am looking which file and where is this file and what is the command  ,  Thanks

Comment: Are you connecting to the Server via SSH or logining in locally on a tty?

Answer (score 0):

You can to it with `setxkbmap`
`sudo apt-get install x11-xkb-utils`
`man setxkbmap` to get the right syntax.

Comment: The question suggests this is for a server's TTY. I *think* `setxkbmap` is going to be X-specific.

Comment: You are right, it works only with X or x forwaring over SSH.

Comment: I am connected remotely to the the server via vmware vsphere client  using VPN ,  I can connect with ssh also

Comment: The answer above just works with x11 forwarding. You could use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` to change it, but you would have to change it back before you log out. As of yet i haven't found a way to do it user specific without x11 forwarding.